# array of objects in yup validation not working

Tags: yup

```
    export const licenseKeySchema = yup
      .object<Partial<apiTypes.LicenseKey>>()
      .shape({
        username: yup.string().required(),
        lastUpdatedOn: yup.number().required(),
        licenseKey: yup.string().required(),
        expiry: yup.number().required()
      });
    
    export const endpointSchema = yup.object<Partial<apiTypes.Endpoint>>({
      hostname: yup.string().required(),
      ipAddress: yup.string().required(),
      lcmIdentifier: yup.string().required(),
      licenseKeys: yup.array().of(licenseKeySchema).required()
    });
    
    
    export interface LicenseKey {
      vmid: string;
      createdBy: string;
      lastModifiedBy: string;
      createdOn: number;
      lastUpdatedOn: number;
      properties?: any;
      username: string;
      hostname: string;
      lcmIdentifier: string;
      licenseKey: string;
      orgId: string;
      accessKey: string;
      lemansGatewayUri: string;
      message?: string;
      accessKeyLink: string;
      expiry: number;
      lastHeartBeat?: any;
      ipAddress: string;
    }
    
    export interface Endpoint {
      hostname: string;
      licenseKeys: LicenseKey[];
      ipAddress: string;
      lcmIdentifie

 }
```

- 

> getting below error  Type 'ArraySchema<Shape<Partial |
> undefined, { username: string; lastUpdatedOn: number; licenseKey:
> string; expiry: number; }>>' is not assignable to type
> 'MixedSchema<LicenseKey[] | undefined>'.
> The types of 'nullable(...).nullable' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '{ (isNullable?: true | undefined): NullableArraySchema<Shape<Partial | undefined, {
> username: string; lastUpdatedOn: number; licenseKey: string; expiry:
> number; }>>; (isNullable: false): ArraySchema<...>; (isNullable?:
> boolean | undefined): ArraySchema<...>; }' is not assignable to type
> '{ (isNullable?: true | undefined): MixedSchema<LicenseKey[] | null |
> undefined>; (isNullable: false): MixedSchema<LicenseKey[] |
> undefined>; (isNullable?: boolean | undefined): MixedSchema<...>; }'.
> Types of parameters 'isNullable' and 'isNullable' are incompatible.
> Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true | undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your `licenseKeySchema` to be a `Partial` of `LicenseKey`:

```js
    export const licenseKeySchema = yup
      .object<Partial<apiTypes.LicenseKey>>() <- this line
      .shape({ ... })
```

so you must do the same in your `Endpoint`:

```js
    export interface Endpoint {
      hostname: string;
      licenseKeys: Partial<LicenseKey>[]; <- this line
      ipAddress: string;
      ...
    }
```

EDIT:

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yxmshr?file=yup.ts

It has an error in it. As soon as you uncomment the commented out line and comment out the one above it in the `Endpoint` interface, then it works.

Comment: Try harder, I fixed it in a stackblitz. I’m AFK right now and can’t reproduce the code for you.

Comment: error TS2322: Type 'ArraySchema<Shape<Partial<LicenseKey> | undefined, { username: string; lastUpdatedOn: number; licenseKey: string; expiry: number; }>, object>' is not assignable to type 'Ref | Schema<Partial<LicenseKey>[] | undefined, object> | MixedSchema<Partial<LicenseKey>[] | undefined, object> | undefined'.

Comment: not sure why it is keep on throwing error about ArraySchema and MixedSchema

Comment: @dhavalthakor - the error is gone in the stackblitz that is posted in the answer and it has been explained why.

Comment: I had a similar problem, yup was not letting me use `.nullable()`. This answer helped to remember that the property in my interface also needs to be nullable